# Mot le plus approprié pour remplacer « snapshot »

Tags: anglais, choix-de-mot, terminologie, informatique

Je suis en train de développer une application web bilingue et pour une des fonctionnalités le terme anglais m'est venu instantanément, mais je ne parviens pas à trouver un équivalent français aussi significatif et concis.

Le mot en question est « snapshot ». Un utilisateur peut créer un projet et créer des phases à ce projet. Lors des phases on peut entrer différentes données et des commentaires sur celle-ci. Si une date parait importante dans le projet, mais ne correspond pas à un changement de phase, on peut décider de créer un « snapshot » à cette date. Ce qui permet de pouvoir visualiser les données telles qu'elles étaient à cette date.

Ce mot se retrouve sur un bouton, donc il ne faut pas que ça soit une phrase.

J'ai envisagé plusieurs alternatives comme « sauvegarde », « sauvegarde d'état », « sauvegarde instantanée », « figer les données », « photo à ce jour », etc. Par contre, aucun mot me semble vraiment avoir autant d'impact et de clarté que le mot anglais « snapshot ».

Je cherche donc un mot ou courte une expression, car en ce moment je considère peut-être laisser le mot « snapshot ».

Comment: « Par contre, aucun mot me semble vraiment avoir autant d'impact et de clarté que le mot anglais _snapshot_. »  Effet de perspective, à cause de ton travail, tu n'es pas aussi conscient du sens principal du mot anglais que de celui des propositions de traduction, que donc tu cherches à rendre plus précises en perdant de la concision.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Tu as probablement raison. D'où mon utilisation du groupe « me semble »!

Comment: Je suis surpris que personne n'ait proposé "capture".

Comment: @julien Quelqu'un avait proposé "capture instantanée", mais la réponse a été supprimée pour une raison qui m'échappe encore...

Comment: Il y a des tres bonnes réponses maintenant, alors j'ai pensé que la miene etais trop courte...

Comment: @yms Personellement, je trouvais ta réponse bien, et je m'en suis servi! Même si elle est courte elle reste «on topic»!

Comment: Merci pour l'encouragement :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On peut également utiliser la forme contractée (où le nom est sous-entendu, comme dans le domaine de la photo) : (prendre/faire) **un instantané**

Ou alors éventuellement **état antérieur** ? C'est moins concis mais pourquoi pas... à envisager.

Comment: Pour info, **instantané** est d'ailleurs la traduction ustilisée par [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) pour **snapshot**, dans le sens de point de sauvegarde dans la "vie" d'une machine virtuelle.

Comment: Merci, j'ai finalement décidé d'utiliser instantané sur le bouton directement et j'y ai ajouter une petit icône d'appareil photo à côté pour faire le lien avec la photographie.

Answer (score 6):

Il me semble que la traduction la plus juste de snapshot est instantané, qui montre bien que la situation rendue n'est pas forcément cohérente et stable. C'est la [position de wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Snapshot_%28stockage_informatique%29&redirect=no) ; que ceux qui sont pas d'accord la modifie.

Peut être aussi **photo**, tout simplement ?

Cependant, le snapshot que je connais ne correspond pas à la description que vous en faites : à ma connaissance en tous cas, ce n'est pas une date importante, mais la date présente, et il n'est pas question de retourner dans le passé pour retrouver un snapshot : si la date est passée, que le snapshot n'avait pas été fait à cette date, alors le snapshot est impossible ; c'est comme si vous vouliez prendre une photo d'un événement passé.

Pour ce que vous dites, des mots comme situation, état, iraient mieux ?... Instantané va bien aussi, même si vous ne décrivez pas le même snapshot que celui que je connais :-)

Comment: J'avais le sentiment qu'Hugo avait la même définition que toi. Ce n'est peut-être qu'un malentendu dans la manière de le décrire. Je ne crois pas que l'application décrite permette des 'rétro-snapshot', ils doivent vraisemblablement avoir été faits à un instant donné du passé pour pouvoir être rappelés.

Comment: C'est effectivement ce que je voulais dire, je me suis peut être mal exprimé. Un fois que le « snapshot » est pris on ne peut plus le modifier, mais on peut revenir le consulter pour revoir l'état des données à ce moment là.

Comment: Bon très bien je m'incline :-) Surtout qu'en plus on est tous d'accord finalement.

Answer (score 6):

En lien avec la photo, je propose **cliché**.

Comment: C'est vu et revu comme traduction.

Answer (score 5):

Hors contexte, j'aurais aussi tendance à traduire par "instantané"; mais dans l'application en elle-même je me demande si ce sera suffisament clair.

Je proposerais plutôt *conserver* (ou *préserver*), qui me paraît indiquer clairement que l'on veut pouvoir garder une vision de l'état actuel pour une consultation future.

Dans un style plus poétique, il y a d'autres mots qui me viennent à l'esprit, comme *figer*, *immortaliser*, *pérenniser*, *fossiliser*, voire *momifier*. J'imagine suppose que la poésie n'est pas le but premier de l'application, mais qui sait, peut-être qu'un de ces mots marquera mieux les utilisateurs (ma préférence va à *fossiliser*).

Comment: Il n'y a pas assez de poésie dans nos applications, nos productions, nos quotidiens. Mais, même si je suis conscient que le rouleau-compresseur de la normalité continuera à invalider quotidiennement et partout ce genre de propositions (comme la tienne ici, Joubarc), je crois que nous y perdons tous un peu quelque chose... *momifier*... ha ha ! J'adore.

Answer (score 3):

Vous pourriez aussi utiliser «capture instantanée», j'ai vu que [ce terme est utilisé sur MSDN dans le cadre de bases de données](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms175876%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Merci de la réponse, j'ai utilisé cette expression dans la phrase de l'attribut « title » sur le lien en question!

Comment: +1 Ou une "capture", tout court.

Answer (score 3):

> Sauvegarde ponctuelle, ou, archivage ponctuel.
>  Sauvegarde période, ou, archivage période.

pour rester près du sens de l'opération effectuée.

On ne peut utiliser *Saisie conservatoire* qui renvoie à contexte juridique, mais

> Conserver cette période?

représente bien l'intention et peuvent s'écrire soit sur deux lignes, soit *ConserverPériode* en typographie *Arial narrow* par exemple.

Je ne suis pas certain que la brièveté syllabique anglo-saxonne soit  transposable, ni que le laisser tel quel soit élégant, surtout si c'est une application 'tout public' qui ne concerne pas l'informatique.

Plutôt que 'faire court', j'opterais pour la solution la plus compréhensible par tous.
Ou alors, laisser *snapshot*, mais mettre une bulle d'aide en ligne, ou un icône renvoyant à un dictionnaire, à une traduction irréprochable.

Answer (score 2):

Un « aperçu », une « capture » ou « point de restauration ».